# How to dynamise an Observable with Restful services in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to dynamise my Observables in my application created via a RESTful api with angular2

```
this.http.get(...)
```

Let's say I have an instance of an observable created via a restful service.

```
getQuestions(): Observable<Question[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.questionsUrl);
}


let questions = getQuestions().subscribe();
```

When I call this ...

```
addQuestion(question:Question): void{
    this.http.post(this.questionsUrl, { value:question.value }).subscribe();
}
```

I would expect my **questions** variable to be augmented with the new question. How can I do this with Observables in Typescript/Angular2 ?

Comment: getQuestions().subscribe(data => this.questions = data); assuming questions is a class prop

Answer (score -1):

All RxJS are asynchronous and the only value returned from `subscribe()` is an object that you can use to unsubscribe.

So if you want to receive data from the `.post()` call you need to make callback that assigns the received data to a variable.

```
var questions;
getQuestions().subscribe(data => {
    questions = data;
});
```